# How can I extend the definition of Part to return Null for Null input specification?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

How to extend `Part` to return `Null` for `Null` input specification. For example if `x[[{2, 4, Null, 3}]]` should return `{b, d, Null, c}` for `x = {a, b, c, d, e}`.

Comment: Messing with low-level system functions like `Part` is generally a bad idea. The likelihood of breaking unexpected parts of the system or causing significant performance degradations is high, especially with over-general changes like the one you propose. I advise defining a separate function with this feature instead of overloading `Part`.

Comment: In addition to what @Szabolcs said, which is very wise, I suspect that you may be trying to deal with the wrong part of the problem. Instead of trying to make `Part` accept `Null` input, you should perhaps sanitize your input, or otherwise modify the function / return values that generate that `Null`.

Comment: If you explain your needs a bit more I may be able to make a better recommendation.  `Part` is an extremely general function it is not clear how Null would/should interact with much of that, e.g. assignments.  Is `x` always a simple list?

Answer (score 7):

This is *almost* implemented in [`Query`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html):

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e};

Query[{2, 4, Null &, 3}][list]
```

> ```
> {b, d, Null, c}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Also:

```
ClearAll[partF1, partF2]
partF1 = Block[{Null = {}}, Extract[ List /@ #2]@#] /. {} -> Null &;
partF2 = Replace[#2 , x : Except[Null] :> #[[x]], {1}] &;

partF1[{a, b, c, d, e}, {2, Null, 3, Null, 1}]
```

> {b, Null, c, Null, a}

```
partF2[{a, b, c, d, e}, {2, Null, 3, Null, 1}]
```

> {b, Null, c, Null, a}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e};

part = 
  Lookup[
    MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> #1 &] @ #1,
    #2,
    Null] &;

part[list, {2, Null, 3, Null, 1}]
```

{b, Null, c, Null, a}

Answer (score 0):

I agree overloading `Part` is fraught with danger. I suggest editing the index specification of `Part` in a wrapper function and back-filling the `Null`s. `nullPart` perform this action for multi-dimensional `List`s.

```
ClearAll[nullPart]
SetAttributes[nullPart, HoldFirst]
nullPart[hPart_Part] :=
 Module[
  {params = Apply[Sequence, Hold[hPart], {1}]
   , indexWrap, nullIndex}
  , indexWrap = Switch[Length@params, 2, Identity, _, List]
  ; nullIndex = Position[indexWrap[ReleaseHold[params[[2 ;;]]]], Null]
  ; params[[2 ;;]] = Delete[indexWrap[ReleaseHold[params[[2 ;;]]]], nullIndex]
  ; Switch[indexWrap, Identity, Flatten, _, Identity]@
   Fold[
    #2[#1] &
    , Switch[indexWrap, Identity, List, _, Identity][Part @@ params]
    , Function[loc
      , Map[
        Insert[Switch[First@loc, 1, List, _, Identity]@Null, Last[loc]]
        , #1
        , loc[[;; -2]] - 1
        ] &
      ] /@ nullIndex
    ]
  ]
```

**1D list**

```
lst = Alphabet[];
```

then

```
nullPart[lst[[{2, 3, Null, 7, 8}]]]
```

> ```
> {"b", "c", Null, "g", "h"}
> ```

```
nullPart[lst[[{2, 3, Null, 7, 8, Null}]]]
```

> ```
> {"b", "c", Null, "g", "h", Null}
> ```

**2D list**

```
lst2D = Partition[Alphabet[], 3];
```

then

```
nullPart[lst2D[[{1, 3, 5}, 1]]]
```

> ```
> {"a", "g", "m"}
> ```

```
nullPart[lst2D[[{1, 3, 5}, {1, Null}]]]
```

> ```
> {{"a", Null}, {"g", Null}, {"m", Null}}
> ```

```
nullPart[lst2D[[{1, 3, Null, 5}, {1, Null}]]]
```

> ```
> {{"a", Null}, {"g", Null}, {Null, Null}, {"m", Null}}
> ```

**3D list**

```
lst3D = ArrayReshape[Alphabet[], {3, 4, 2}];
```

then

```
nullPart[lst3D[[{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {1, Null, 2}]]]
```

> ```
> {{{"c", Null, "d"}, {"g", Null, "h"}}, {{"s", Null, "t"}, {"w", Null, "x"}}}
> ```

and so on.

Hope this helps.